# Question about geometric multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra

What does it mean to "count by geometric multiplicity". Am I suppose to sum up the dimensions of the eigenspaces?

Comment: It would be nice to know at least the full sentence where this appeared, if not the entire paragraph. It's easier to explain in context.

Comment: Of course, here it is: "A is diagonalizable (under the context of matrices over the complex field) if it has (n) eigenvalues counted by geometric multiplicity"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue is the number of linearly independent vectors associated with each eigenvalue. For example:
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{array}\right]
$$
This matrix has the characteristic polynomial $(1-\lambda)^2$, so the only eigenvalue is $1$. The null space of $A-\lambda I$ is $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$. Because these vectors are linearly dependent, $1$ has geometric multiplicity $1$. This differs from the algebraic multiplicity, which is simply the number of "times" an eigenvalue is a root of the characteristic polynomial, so $1$ would have algebraic multiplicity $2$.

The geometric multiplicity is important for finding whether or not a matrix is diagonalizable. If the geometric multiplicities of each eigenvalue don't add up to $n$, then the matrix is not diagonalizable.